# same number of item in next frame

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

Hi I need that for the next frame I still use the same number of the item.

but with this code Im getting a new number

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Método}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
    \only<1-2>{
        \item<1-2>  Enfoque tradicional basado en la distancia con respecto al origen
        
        \begin{alertblock}{Distancia entre dos puntos [\cite{perk-erik}]}
            \begin{equation}
            \label{eqn:distancia-euclideana}
            D_{e}((i,j),(h,k)) = \left( \sqrt{(j-i)^2+(k-h)^2} \right)
            \end{equation}
            
        \end{alertblock}
}
\only<2-3>{ 
        \item<2-3> Proyección ortogonal en la diagonal del cubo RGB.

    }
    \end{enumerate} 
\only<2>{
        \begin{alertblock}{proyeccion [\cite{JimHeff}]}
            \begin{equation}
            \label{eqn:proyeccion}
            proj_{[\overrightarrow{r}]}(\overrightarrow{p})  = \left\lbrace \frac{\overrightarrow{p} \cdot \overrightarrow{r}}{\overrightarrow{r} \cdot \overrightarrow{r}} \right\rbrace \cdot \overrightarrow{r}
            \end{equation}
            
        \end{alertblock}
    }   
\only<3>{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{imagenes/logo-ucm}
        \caption{figura1}
        \label{fig:figura1}
    \end{figure}
}   
    
\end{frame}
```

[image]

i need that the number in the circle keeps being the same number as before (number 2)

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the `enumerate` environment to the very end and provide separate directives for `\only<2>` and `\only<3>`, respectively. Then, stepping the `enumi` counter immediately after `\only<3>{` fixes the numbering of the item in layer #3.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}  % remove 'demo' option in real document
%% choose the appropriate themes
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}   % is 'spanish' correct?
\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for 'wide' option

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Método}
    
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]

\only<1-2>{
\item<1-2> Enfoque tradicional basado en la distancia con respecto al origen
        
\begin{alertblock}{Distancia entre dos puntos \cite{perk-erik}}
    \begin{equation} \label{eqn:distancia-euclideana}
    D_{e}\bigl((i,j),(h,k)\bigr) = 
           \Bigl( \sqrt{(j-i)^2+(k-h)^2}\, \Bigr)
    \end{equation}         
\end{alertblock}
}


\only<2>{ 
\item<2> Proyección ortogonal en la diagonal del cubo RGB.

\begin{alertblock}{proyeccion \cite{JimHeff}}
    \begin{equation} \label{eqn:proyeccion}
    \proj_{[\vec{r}\,]}(\vec{p}\,)  = 
       \left\lbrace 
       \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}{ \vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}} 
       \right\rbrace \cdot \vec{r}
    \end{equation}        
\end{alertblock}
}   


\only<3>{  
\stepcounter{enumi} % <-- new
\item<3> Proyección ortogonal en la diagonal del cubo RGB.
    
    \medskip
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{imagenes/logo-ucm}
    \caption{figura1}
    \label{fig:figura1}
    \end{figure}
}   

\end{enumerate} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way for not having to write the same item "Proyección ortogonal en la diagonal del cubo RGB." twice ?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega - I'm not sure. Maybe somebody else will provide a separate answer that addresses the issue in your follow-up question.